# How do I identify isolates and delete them in R Statnet

Tags: r, statnet

How do I identify isolates and delete them in R Statnet?

Here is an example code.

```
g2<-network.initialize(10)
add.edge(g2,1,2)
add.edge(g2,2,3)
add.edge(g2,3,4)
add.edge(g2,4,5)
```

This will generate a network where vertices 6,7,8,9, 10 are not connected. These are isolates. So my question is how do I identify isolates and remove them from the network in Statnet library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `sna::isolates` function to detect them and delete the isolates through the `network::delete.vertices` function of the network package (both included in statnet).

In your case:

```
isolates <- sna::isolates(g2)
network::delete.vertices(g2, isolates)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer harald. I apologize for not acknowledging your help sooner.